# unix - cannot execute each result from find files

Tags: shell, unix, sed, command-line, find

```
find . -type f -path '*/browser/components/*/*.react.js' -exec sed -i "" '1 i\
import { logRender } from "../../../common/lib/logger";
' {} +
```

above command only execute 1 file only, the first one instead of each results from:

`find . -type f -path '*/browser/components/*/*.react.js'`

Is there something I missed?

Comment: Maybe the thing is in that the `{} +` construction puts a list of a files found by the `find`?.. Consider to substitute it to the `{} ;`. (As usual, probably you will need to escape the `;`: `{} \;`.)

Answer (score 0):

you can try this;

```
find . -type f -path '*/browser/components/*/*.react.js' -exec sed -i "" '1 i\
import { logRender } from "../../../common/lib/logger";
' {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use SED's `-s` (`--separate`) option:

> `-s, --separate`
>
> consider files as separate rather than as a single continuous long stream.

since *find*'s `-exec command +` action builds a command by appending each selected file name at the end. In particular, the *sed* command will be invoked with multiple files: `sed ... file1 file2 file3 ...`.

Otherwise, process the files sequentially with `find -exec sed -i '...' {} ';'`.

By the way, it's very likely that you are using GNU SED, since `i\` command is a GNU extension. With GNU SED, you don't need to specify an argument for `-i` option.

Also, consider passing the SED script via `-e` (`--expression`) option to avoid ambiguities.

Example:

```
find . -type f -path '*/browser/components/*/*.react.js' -exec sed -s -i -e '1 i\
import { logRender } from "../../../common/lib/logger";
' {} +
```